# Filter Ng-Repeat Results with Variable Found in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have data I am displaying with ng-repeat using AngularJs, unfortunately I have not found a solid way in AngularJs to actively listen for changes in the window.location and respond, but  I have done so in Jquery. I would like to get the results from my Jquery function and filter the ng-repeat results with the parameter. 
 Here is an example of the angular:

```
<div  id="center" class="datagrid">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> ID </th>
                  <th> Phone </th>
                  <th> Address </th>
                  <th> Zip </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy:'id' | filter:{id:clientId} | limitTo: 1 track by $index">
    <td>
     {{client.id}}
  </td>
  <td>
     <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.phone" name="phone" ng-init="updateform.phone=client.phone" type="text "/>
     </div>
    </td>
  <td>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.address" name="address" ng-init="updateform.address = client.address" type="text "/>
    </div>
    </td>
  <td>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.zip" name="zip" ng-init="updateform.zip = client.zip" type="text "/>
     </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Here is JQuery Function:

```
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
     var id = document.location.href.split('about#/')[1];
     console.log(id)
});
```

Comment: you already have a service called $window and a service called $location :')

Comment: I have not been able to use these to dynamically update data with change on url, maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: regardless of whether you use the global window or `$window`, data binding works the same. If you want to use it in your template, assign it to `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `routeProvider` service you can do something like this :

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event){
     var url = $location.url(),
})
```

Comment: I have tried this, and on each new click (dynamically) I am not getting corresponding filtering results